# May I have multiple alias in Vue's router for an specific route?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

The thing is the following, while alias for now covers my needs perfectly, I wonder how to declare multiple aliases for a path, so, would something like this work? Example:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      alias: ['/home', '/home2', '/homeN']
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import('./views/About.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

By this I mean, is it the recommended way to do so? Is there a better practice for that in Vue router?

Comment: This is fine, they even have an [official example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-alias/app.js) doing it.  If you're more worried about misspellings then you could potentially just use a navigation guard on a `*` wildcard path that redirects based on substrings of the route path.

Comment: I guess I missed that part in the documentation, thanks for the clarification @Steven B.!

Comment: Could you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fine, they even have an [official example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-alias/app.js) doing it.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
  routes: [
    { path: '/root', component: Root, alias: '/root-alias' },
    { path: '/home', component: Home,
      children: [
        // absolute alias
        { path: 'foo', component: Foo, alias: '/foo' },
        // relative alias (alias to /home/bar-alias)
        { path: 'bar', component: Bar, alias: 'bar-alias' },
        // multiple aliases
        { path: 'baz', component: Baz, alias: ['/baz', 'baz-alias'] },
        // default child route with empty string as alias.
        { path: 'default', component: Default, alias: '' },
        // nested alias
        { path: 'nested', component: Nested, alias: 'nested-alias',
          children: [
            { path: 'foo', component: NestedFoo }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

If you're more worried about misspellings then you could potentially just use a navigation guard on a `*` wildcard path that redirects based on substrings of the route path.

Answer (score 1):

Actually , what you did should be totally fine. You can provide an array of aliases and vue will understand.

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      alias: ['/home', '/home2', '/homeN']  // multiple aliases
    },
 
  ]
})
```

(I copied your code as I believe it is indeed the answer) .